# Solving 2nd order ODE with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve the following differential equation with `NDSolve`:

```
NDSolve[{(1 + Sqrt[\[Pi] x])*y[x] + x*y'[x] - (x^2)/6*y''[x] == 1, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

Mathematica says it encounters an infinite expression. I've tried shifting the initial point from 0 to 0.1 or 0.01 and it gives a growing exponential function that I think is nonphysical. This DE is an approximation to another DE that has as a solution `MittagLefflerE[q,-x^q]` with `q = 3/2` here, which is decaying. The approximation should hold for 0 < x < 2.

I also tried coding up the solution using an explicit Euler scheme but it gives the same exponential-type solution. I'm pretty sure the solution is not supposed to be growing but I guess I could be wrong.

Any help with the DE is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Mathematica says it got division by zero, because your initial conditions are not valid. They produce no solution.

The analytical solution to

$$
\left( 1+\sqrt {\pi\,x} \right) y \left( x \right) +x{\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) -1/6\,{x}^{2}{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}
{x}^{2}}}y \left( x \right) =0
$$

Is given by Maple as (DSolve does not seem to be able to solve this, after some time waiting).

$$
y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{x}^{7/2+1/2\,\sqrt {73}}
{\mbox{$_0$F$_1$}(\ ;\,1+2\,\sqrt {73};\,24\,\sqrt {\pi}\sqrt {x})}+{
\it \_C2}\,{x}^{7/2-1/2\,\sqrt {73}}
{\mbox{$_0$F$_1$}(\ ;\,1-2\,\sqrt {73};\,24\,\sqrt {\pi}\sqrt {x})}
$$

Where $F_1$ is `hypergeom` function. Taking derivative of the above gives

$$
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) ={\frac {{\it \_C1}\,{x}^{
7/2+1/2\,\sqrt {73}} \left( 7/2+1/2\,\sqrt {73} \right) 
{\mbox{$_0$F$_1$}(\ ;\,1+2\,\sqrt {73};\,24\,\sqrt {\pi}\sqrt {x})}}{x
}}+12\,{\frac {{\it \_C1}\,{x}^{7/2+1/2\,\sqrt {73}}
{\mbox{$_0$F$_1$}(\ ;\,2+2\,\sqrt {73};\,24\,\sqrt {\pi}\sqrt {x})}
\sqrt {\pi}}{ \left( 1+2\,\sqrt {73} \right) \sqrt {x}}}+{\frac {{\it 
\_C2}\,{x}^{7/2-1/2\,\sqrt {73}} \left( 7/2-1/2\,\sqrt {73} \right) 
{\mbox{$_0$F$_1$}(\ ;\,1-2\,\sqrt {73};\,24\,\sqrt {\pi}\sqrt {x})}}{x
}}+12\,{\frac {{\it \_C2}\,{x}^{7/2-1/2\,\sqrt {73}}
{\mbox{$_0$F$_1$}(\ ;\,2-2\,\sqrt {73};\,24\,\sqrt {\pi}\sqrt {x})}
\sqrt {\pi}}{ \left( 1-2\,\sqrt {73} \right) \sqrt {x}}}
$$

You can now see that at $x=0$ there is a division by zero.

So your initial conditions are not valid or something wrong with your equations (may be did not copy it correctly from the book?).

Comment: What a formidable solution! I see this now. Thank you, I'll mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way out is to give a starting value to $x$ to be `10^-4` not `0`.

```
NDSolve[{(1 + Sqrt[π x])*y[x] + x*y'[x] - (x^2)/6*y''[x] == 1, y[10^-4] == 1, 
          y'[10^-4] == 0}, y[x], {x, 10^-4, 2}]

Plot[y[x] /. %, {x, 10^-4, 2}]
```

Comment: I was able to find this solution before but I'm not sure it's physical. I'm looking for a decaying solution.

Comment: @Buddhapus Then you should check your equation.